# Multiple background colors in scrollable flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `flexbox` (`flex-direction: row`) with 2 columns of content and a fixed height. I want the left and right column to have a red and blue background respectively. If either of the columns overflow, the `flexbox`'s scrollbar appears (the overflowed part is still red/blue). If a column's content height is less than the `flexbox`'s height, the space below should still be red/blue.

Without using gradient colors or javascript, how can I achieve this effect?

Demo (I want the gray part to be blue):

```css
#c1 {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-items: baseline;
}
#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
    <div id="left">
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

Methods that don't work:

- Setting `align-items: stretch`: overflowed part will be gray
- Add a `position: absolute` `div` that overlays the `flexbox`, solely for the background: this `div` will have the wrong width if the scrollbar is visible.

Comment: You can remove the `align-items` and the right side will stretch to fit the height of the parent. Or you could change the background on the parent to blue. Would either of those work? I'm assuming you know that and need align-items and don't want to change the parent background.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes those don't work because: if `align-items` is stretched, the overflowed part will be gray. Also, either columns may or may not overflow so the parent cannot be a single color.

Comment: Is it ok for you to change the markup a little bit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from Nithin Charly's answer, I got this:

(doesn't work properly in IE due to bugs)

```css
#c1 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fix height for parent and using display flex, the height of children is auto fit to height parent. So in this case, you need to use js to change the height of children. If you don't want to use js, you just do as bellow:

```css
#c1 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  background-color: blue;
}
#left, #right{
  display:table-cell;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
    <div id="left">
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now you have three columns. Fix that, and briefly explain your answer by text. Why use table-cell instead of flex? And you have an upvote ;)

Comment: see [this picture](http://imgur.com/a/TdiDK). Maybe because of the width: 200px. Anyway your answer now is ok, but not perfect. Please briefly explain by text. [While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to use `display: table;` for your container, and `display: table-cell;` for your columns. The elements acting like tables, you can obtain the rendering you want.

I had to add another container thought, due to the fact that you cannot limit the height of a `table` so easily.

```css
#c1 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  background-color: blue;
}

#left, #right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
  <div class="table">
    <div id="left">
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap left and right div with another div, set display flex and min-height:min-content for that div. also set height 100% for left and right div.

```css
    #c1 {
      background-color: gray;
      display: flex;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

#wrap{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  min-height:min-content;
}
#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  height:100%;
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
   

 <div id="c1">
      <div id='wrap'>
        <div id="left">
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
          <div>line</div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
          <div>line</div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with `align-items: baseline`. You can just leave that out or replace it with stretch and you'll get what you're after.

```css
#c1 {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* align-items: baseline; */

}
#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
    <div id="left">
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div>line</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought also, but scroll down and you'll see the bottom of each column is still gray.