# Height issue with elements in a row using flexbox and scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a couple of element which are positioned horizontally, but they are taller than the parent, meeaning they scroll. It looks like this
[image]

Although the scroll behaviour is correct, the content of the first block overflows.

The HTML looks like this

```
<section>
    <div> <!-- very long content --> </div>
    <div>b</div>
    ....
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow:auto;
}

div {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/2/)

As you can see in the demo, the element with the green background color is not tall enough to fit all the content. How can this be achieved ? It would be nice if all **div**s have the same height, is that possible?

Comment: Just try to remove the "height:100px" of section css. It will allow the section to cover all the content. Is it what you want?

Comment: If you want it to cover text in 100px height then use  "overflow-y:scroll;" inside div css.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274225/multiple-background-colors-in-scrollable-flexbox

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, which does not solve it given the section is set to a fixed height, though if the fixed height was merely to force the scroll and show the issue, let us know beforehand, so the suggested solutions become appropriate. Also, by simply remove the height on my attempt, you get the same result, though will be able to adjust it based on the surrounding elements, which the accepted one never will

Comment: You're right, the accepted answer is not exactly what I want, but I was able to modify the given answer to what I needed: https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/9/

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri But my answer already does exactly that...with much simpler, shorter and less error prone code

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri You can of course accept any answer you want, though accepting one and then use the concept of someone else's might make users stop spending their personal time on your future questions

Comment: You're right, sorry for that!

Comment: Thank you, and for acknowledge my way of thinking, plus 1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all to have the same height, add a wrapper between the section and the div items and let it be the flex container.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/10/)

Stack snippet

```css
section {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section > div {
  display: flex;
}

section > div > div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div>a ge g er g er gerge rgera ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er
      gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgergg</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

For only the overflowed element to maintain background color on the overflowing part, add an extra inner wrapper to each item and let it inherit the background color.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/13/)

Stack snippet

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section > div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}

section > div > div {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <div>a ge g er g er gerge rgera ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er
      gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgerga ge g er g er gerge rgergg</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>b</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>c</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>d</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>e</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `height:auto`; style instead of fixed height
see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/5/)

```
section {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: auto;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow:auto;
}
div {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Or you can avoid height style as in [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/6/)

Comment: Based on your solution I was able to achieve what I needed:  jsfiddle.net/3ch19qjq/9 Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If you you want all the items to be 100px high without overflow then set `overflow: hidden;`. If you want all the items to be as high as the highest item, then remove the `height` property.